# FTP command STOR error: 553 Could not determine cwdir: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp, command, store

I have the following scenario:

```
< 220 FTP server ready.
> USER ***
< 331 Password required for ***.
> PASS splav23
< 230 User *** logged in.  Access restrictions apply.
> CWD /
< 250 CWD command successful.
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I.
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (78,54,275,45,42,1)
> STOR /var/www/www.abc.com/public_html_files/public/files_feed/abc.zip
< 553 Could not determine cwdir: No such file or directory.
```

I don't understand why after STOR command I receive "553 Could not determine cwdir: No such file or directory.". For this reason I cand't upload my file to server. How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the path is correct? Your FTP account may be chrooted so that only part of the path is valid.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing the directory structure (assuming that what you have is correct)

Try this (please don't mod down if it doesn't work, I'm just saying try):

```
CD /var/www/www.abc.com/public_html_files/public/files_feed/
STOR abc.zip
```

There doesn't appear to be a problem with your syntax.  So either the directory doesn't exist or your don't have access to the directory `CHMOD 777`